# HiGHS solver returns error when using Pyomo Kernel

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo, linear-optimization, highs

I've been trying to get the HiGHS solver to work with the Pyomo kernel interface, but when I try to solve it it gives me this error: "AttributeError: unreadable attribute 'domain'".

I created a simple example to reproduce is - does HiGHS not not support the kernel?

```
import pyomo.kernel as pmo
from pyomo.contrib import appsi

m = pmo.block()
m.x1 = pmo.variable(domain=pmo.NonNegativeReals)
m.c = pmo.constraint(m.x1 == 5)
m.o = pmo.objective(m.x1*10, sense=1)
opt = pmo.SolverFactory("appsi_highs")
#opt = appsi.solvers.Highs()
result = opt.solve(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyomo's interface to HiGHS does not currently support kernel.